# How to rsync files with --files-from with quantifier?

Tags: rsync

I want to move from one server to another and I won´t lost special logfiles (like mail.logs), so want to rsync the files with the --files-from option. But I can´t use a quantifier like * or {0..9} in the file list.

`rsync -avR --files-from=/backup/filelists/filelist1.txt / $DESTSRV:"$DESTPATH"`

for example I want to rsync all mail server log files

> /var/log/mail.log
>
> /var/log/mail.log.1
>
> /var/log/mail.log.2.gz
>
> /var/log/mail.log.3.gz
>
> /var/log/mail.log.4.gz

But in the */backup/filelists/filelist1.txt* I can´t use

`/var/log/mail*`

or

`/var/log/mail.log.{2..10}.gz`

I got the following error

`rsync: link_stat "/var/log/mail*" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

Anybody knows a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching and trying I found another solution that fits to me:

```
cat /backup/fileslists/filelist1.txt | { while read line; do rsync -avzR $line "$DESTSRV":"$DESTPATH"/; done; }
```

This code reads the input file line by line and sync it with rsync. In this case I could use any quantifier :).